# How to see what's on the terminal output remotely?

Tags: ssh

If I have the output of a command printed to a log file, then I can ssh into that desktop from my laptop and view the file.

However,if I did not specify to append the output to a log file, how would I go about to know what's the output on a specific terminal window? Using xprop, I know the windows id and class.  Is it possible to view the output while ssh from a laptop?

Comment: maybe the followings will help: https://serverfault.com/questions/858413/how-can-i-watch-a-terminal-window-remotely https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session ... anyway I think you may have more luck asking/searching on superuser or other channels more suited to sysadmin topics